# How to write about pouring water?

Tags: fiction, description, showing-telling

When someone treats a wound, like a burn, there’s this sound of the water pouring down, hitting the sink. Does anyone know what the sound is called? What things should I keep in mind while writing something like that, where someone treats a burn?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. The sound of pouring water? Why not turn on your faucet and listen to it, then try to describe that sound for yourself. If I tell you how I would do it, you'll only know how I would describe it.

Comment: @Fayth85 I think the querant meants the sizzling sound when water touches a hot surface... I think. It's not very clear

Answer (score 1):

To me, the courage and strength of medical caregivers is amazing.  When I write about them, I always try to recognize how difficult and emotionally challenging their lives are.  Burn treatment is probably the worst part of any healer's day.  If a story called me to write about it, I would want the writing to be sensual (i.e. filled with sensory words).  I would be tempted to bring in smells which probably aren't very pleasant, but maybe sounds are a better way to portray what the caregiver is going through...

*The sounds and sensations of the procedure calmed her.  The rhythmic gurgling of the tap water swirling down the drain.  The moist chill of each strip of gauze on her fingertips.  She found focus in the familiar process and it allowed her hands to move smoothly, gently applying each dressing to cover the horrible wound.  And that focus was crucial.  It helped her continue doing everything which was needed, despite her patient's screams.*